# Embedding HornetQ 2.2.14 with Jboss-5.1.0.GA

Tags: jboss5.x, hornetq

I have successfully embedded HornetQ 2.2.14 with JBoss-5.1.0.GA by following this link http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/quickstart-guide/en/html_single/#installation.jboss.as5.

but I am getting exception as,

```
Error installing to Real: name=vfsfile:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real

org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying: vfsfile:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/hornetq-jboss-beans.xml
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.deploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:125)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.internalDeploy(AbstractRealDeployerWithInput.java:102)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception loading class for ScopeKey addition.
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.deploy(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:126)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.AS5RecoveryRegistry from BaseClassLoader@bf5dc1{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1a45a7f{name=vfsfile:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@152e961{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1479feb} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@20020219[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4oz19-xy0sz8-hghy7wgr-1-hghy8fcm-10 real=vfsmemory://5c4oz19-xy0sz8-hghy7wgr-1-hghy8fcm-10], FileHandler@29532276[path=hornetq.sar context=file:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/ real=file:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:448)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.addBeanComponent(BeanMetaDataFactoryVisitor.java:63)
    ... 36 more
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.AS5RecoveryRegistry from BaseClassLoader@bf5dc1{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@1a45a7f{name=vfsfile:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/ domain=ClassLoaderDomain@152e961{name=DefaultDomain parentPolicy=BEFORE parent=org.jboss.bootstrap.NoAnnotationURLClassLoader@1479feb} roots=[MemoryContextHandler@20020219[path= context=vfsmemory://5c4oz19-xy0sz8-hghy7wgr-1-hghy8fcm-10 real=vfsmemory://5c4oz19-xy0sz8-hghy7wgr-1-hghy8fcm-10], FileHandler@29532276[path=hornetq.sar context=file:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/ real=file:/home/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default-with-hornetq/deploy/hornetq.sar/]]  delegates=null exported=[] <IMPORT-ALL>NON_EMPTY}}
18:35:56,302 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
18:35:56,345 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
18:35:56,372 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8443
18:35:56,402 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 49s:604ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Either try the thing mentioned in [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/197820):

Change

```
<bean name="AS5RecoveryRegistry"
    class="org.hornetq.jms.server.recovery.AS5RecoveryRegistry">
```

to

```
<bean name="AS5RecoveryRegistry"
  class="org.jboss.as.integration.hornetq.recovery.AS5RecoveryRegistry">
```

in deploy/hornetq.sar/hornetq-jboss-beans.xml.

If that doesn't work, according to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-943 you're out of luck:

> HornetQ is only supported with JBoss EAP 5.1.2

Note that it is possible to just comment out the automatic recovery. That might be potentially harmful however.